# On inequality involving logarithm

Tags: inequality

I have been researching in order to do a paperwork about inequalities for my university and I ran into this inequality from a book I have been trying to understand without results.
It says:

> For every $t\geq 1$ we have that
> \begin{equation}
> \ln(t)\leq \frac{(t+1)(t^3-1)}{3t(t^2+1)}
> \end{equation}

The book also sais that to prove it, it suffices to show that the right side has a larger derivative for $t>1$. But I dont see how and why would this imply the inequality, also I have been trying to prove that the derivative is larger and I also cant..
Can someone help?

The book: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321420

Comment: Is $\log$ the Natural logarithm? Then better use $\ln$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: If $f(a) = g(a)$ and $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$ for all $x,$ then for all $x$ we also have $\int_a^x f'(t) - g'(t) dt \geq 0,$ so $(f(x) - g(x)) - (f(a) - g(a)) \geq 0,$ so $f(x) - g(x) \geq 0$ and $f(x) \geq g(x).$

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(t)=\log(t)-\frac{(t+1)(t^3-1)}{3t(t^2+1)}.$$

Then $f(1)=0$, so if you can show $f'(t)\le0$ for $t>1$ it follows that $f(t)\le0$ for $t\ge1$, for example by the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side $f(t)$ of the inequality has a zero at $t=1$, thus $\ln(1) = f(1)$.  If you manage to show that

$$f'(t) \geqslant \ln't =\frac1t \quad\text{ for all } t\geqslant 1 $$

then it follows that $f(t)\geqslant \ln(t)$ for all $t\geqslant 1$ because $f$ grows faster than $\ln$. (And the functions that are involved are smooth enough).

And similarly for $t\leqslant 1$.